# overlay map with different colour

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have this GADM geodataframe of Netherlands, and I want to plot the overlay map of Amsterdam, Utrecht, The Hague, and Rotterdam with different colors on top of the GADM of Netherlands. But, I cannot change the color of the overlay map.

This is my attempt:

```
NL_boundaries = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/zaa_k/Documents/0.Thesis/Datasets/GADM/gadm36_NLD_2.shp")

NL_boundaries_Ams = NL_boundaries[NL_boundaries['NAME_2']=='Amsterdam']
NL_boundaries_Ams = NL_boundaries[NL_boundaries['NAME_2']=='Rotterdam']
NL_boundaries_Ut = NL_boundaries[NL_boundaries['NAME_2']=='Utrecht']
NL_boundaries_Hag = NL_boundaries[NL_boundaries['NAME_2']=="'s-Gravenhage"]

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 12))
ax = NL_boundaries.plot(axes=ax)
lims = plt.axis('equal')
for poly in NL_boundaries['geometry']:
    gpd.plotting.plot_multipolygon(ax, poly, facecolor='red', linewidth=0.025)
for poly in NL_boundaries_Ams['geometry']:
    gpd.plotting.plot_multipolygon(ax, poly, alpha=1, facecolor='red', linewidth=0)
for poly in NL_boundaries_Ut['geometry']:
    gpd.plotting.plot_multipolygon(ax, poly, alpha=1, facecolor='red', linewidth=0)
for poly in NL_boundaries_Rot['geometry']:
    gpd.plotting.plot_multipolygon(ax, poly, alpha=1, facecolor='red', linewidth=0)
for poly in NL_boundaries_Hag['geometry']:
    gpd.plotting.plot_multipolygon(ax, poly, alpha=1, facecolor='red', linewidth=0)
ax.set_axis_off()
f.suptitle('Areas with smallest population')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

and this is the undesirable result:
[image]

anybody can help me coloring Amsterdam, Utrecht, The Hague and Rotterdam to other color? thanks

Comment: It would be easier to debug this if we had access to the data. Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. It is this simple.
First, extract the desired area of each GADM area that we want to highlight:

```
NL_boundaries = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/zaa_k/Documents/0.Thesis/Datasets/GADM/gadm36_NLD_2.shp")
NL_boundaries_Ams = NL_boundaries[NL_boundaries['NAME_2']=='Amsterdam']
NL_boundaries_Rot = NL_boundaries[NL_boundaries['NAME_2']=='Rotterdam']
NL_boundaries_Ut = NL_boundaries[NL_boundaries['NAME_2']=='Utrecht']
NL_boundaries_Hag = NL_boundaries[NL_boundaries['NAME_2']=="'s-Gravenhage"]
```

Don't forget to set the bounding box of each area that we want to highlight:

```
# Bounding Box four cities
NL_boundaries_Ams.total_bounds
NL_boundaries_Rot.total_bounds
NL_boundaries_Ut.total_bounds
NL_boundaries_Hag.total_bounds
xlim = ([NL_boundaries_Rot.total_bounds[0],  NL_boundaries_Ut.total_bounds[2]])
ylim = ([NL_boundaries_Rot.total_bounds[1],  NL_boundaries_Ams.total_bounds[3]])
```

and then just plot each of the layer of GADM areas on top of each other like this:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(25, 25))
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
ax = NL_boundaries.plot(axes=ax, alpha=0.1, edgecolor= 'k')
ax = NL_boundaries_Ams.plot(axes=ax, alpha=1)
ax = NL_boundaries_Rot.plot(axes=ax, alpha=1)
ax = NL_boundaries_Ut.plot(axes=ax, alpha=1)
ax = NL_boundaries_Hag.plot(axes=ax, alpha=1)
ax = dataPoints0.plot(axes=ax, color='red')
ax = dataPoints1.plot(axes=ax, color='cyan')
ax = dataPoints2.plot(axes=ax, color='magenta')
ax = dataPoints3.plot(axes=ax, color='orange')
ax = dataPoints4.plot(axes=ax, color='black')
ax = dataPoints5.plot(axes=ax, color='lime')
ax = dataPoints6.plot(axes=ax, color='blueviolet')
ax = dataPoints7.plot(axes=ax, color='turquoise')

plt.title('K-cluster = 8')
```